# Convert React function component to class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React.js and I want to transform my function in a class. Here is my code :

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import classes from "./Datepicker.css";

const Datepicker = () => {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
    return (
        <DatePicker className="custom-select" dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" selected={startDate}
                    onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}/>
    );
};

export default Datepicker;
```

I thought to this :

```
class Datepicker extends Component {
    render(){
        const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());    
        
        return (
            <DatePicker className="custom-select"    dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" selected={startDate}
                onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}/>
        )
    }
}

export default Datepicker;
```

But I got this :

`React Hook "useState" cannot be called in a class component.`

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: The answer might not be to use a class, as hooks can do everything a class component can do now.

Comment: Yes but I want now to have a class because I need it.

Comment: Why would you need a class?

Answer (score 3):

State is an instance variable in class components, and your setter needs to be a method.

```js
class Datepicker extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {startDate: new Date()};
    }
    
    setStartDate = (startDate) => {
      this.setState({startDate});
    }

    render(){
        const {startDate} = this.state;
        
        return (
            <DatePicker 
                className="custom-select"    
                dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" 
                selected={startDate}
                onChange={this.setStartDate}
            />
        )
    }
}

export default Datepicker;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use state variable in class components. You can read more about component state [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do)

```
class Datepicker extends Component {
    state = { startDate: new Date() };
   
    setStartDate = (startDate) => {
      this.setState({ startDate });
    }

    render(){
        const { startDate } = this.state;
        
        return (
            <DatePicker className="custom-select" dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" selected={startDate}
                onChange={this.setStartDate}/>
        )
    }
}

export default Datepicker;
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to use react hooks like 'useState', 'useEffect' etc inside a class component.
Though you can use `this.setState` to implement something similar with class component

```
class Datepicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date(),
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { startDate } = this.state

    return (
      <DatePicker className="custom-select" dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" selected={startDate}
        onChange={date => this.setState({ startDate: date })} />
    )
  }
}

export default Datepicker;
```

Why do you want to use class component though? Is there a specific case?